# how to write pretty URLs without htaccess file in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, pretty-urls

### Pretty URLs without htaccess

I want to write pretty URL like : 
**http://yousite.com/member/1/** instead of **http://yousite.com/index.php?page=member&id=1**  
But i did with htaccess file and now i want to do this without htaccess file because sometimes you don't have permission to edit htaccess file on server.

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: Maybe a better forum to ask this question would be http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Apache server and AcceptPathInfo is enabled, then you can just use links like /index.php/nice/looking/url.
The "index.php" in the middle of the URL might look a little strange, but I don't think it's possible to have it look better without .htaccess

Else, you could ask your hoster to redirect any URL to /index.php so that you can handle URL rewriting without having /index.php in your URL.

Then you can just use a regex match to detect what file to include.
preg_match('@[/]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@', $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"], $matches) ($matches will contain all "parts" of the url in an array)

Be careful with including the files, use a whitelist so you're sure nobody would be able to load internal files.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create a new folder dynamically for each member with a simple index file inside that includes your front controller, but even if it's possible, you probably don't want to do that, and instead want to change your host.

Answer (score 0):

I might have this **Single Line of Code** inside `index.php` page if i don't want to use `.htaccess`.

**Pseudo code:** Get the ID and Redirect the user

**Short Explanation :** Concat the id that you got in the url and redirect to your desired location with that id

**Real Code**

`header('Location: http://yousite.com/member/'.$_GET['id'].'/');`